# Brew install imagemagick curl fails

Tags: mac-osx, bash, curl, imagemagick

I am getting the following error when trying to install imagemagick via brew on OS X Mountain Lion. It appears to be a curl error - hence why it's on SF not another of the Stack Exchange sites.

```
brew install imagemagick
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.27.tar.gz

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Error: Download failed: http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.27.tar.gz
```

Is it possible to pick an alternative download location when running the `brew install imagemagick` command?

Is this a known problem, I have searched for similar issues but none seem to be the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having this exact problem (today as well, found your post while searching for a result)

The following worked for me:

```
cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew
curl -O http://fossies.org/unix/privat/pkg-config-0.27.tar.gz
brew install imagemagick
```

Basically Homebrew will not re-download a file that it has cached, so its just about downloading the file from somewhere else (finding it was the hard part)

Comment: Great, thanks! I was just in the process of trying to find that file aswell! You've saved me a chunk of wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a `/Homebrew` folder in my `/Library/Caches` directory. I made one and got the file, but `brew install graphviz` still tried the old formula's URL.

I instead went to `/usr/local/Library/Formula` and edited the url property of `pkg-config.rb` to be that new URL from Stephen's answer.

This worked well, and then I did a brew update to reset the recipes.